# NMF clustering not giving results

Tags: r, genomics, gene-expression, clustering, modelling

I'm trying to run the Non-Negative Matrix Factorization(NMF) for my Gene Expression dataset which was originally in matrix form. But it throws errors as given below:

```
expr <- read_excel("./expr.xlsx")
expr<- as.matrix(expr)

#removing the first column containing gene symbols before clustering
expr_rm <- expr[,-1]
class(expr_rm)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

So converted these expr_rm to numeric:

```
expr_rm <- as.numeric(expr_rm)

#removing negative values for running NMF
eps <- .Machine$double.eps
expr_rm[expr_rm<=0] = eps

estimate <- NMF::nmf(expr_rm, 3, nrun = 10, method = "lee", seed = 123)
```

> Error: NMF::nmf - 10/10 fit(s) threw an error.
> Error(s) thrown:
> run #1: 'x' must be numeric
> Timing stopped at: 1.95 0.14 4.4*

```
cluster <- cbind(names(NMF::predict(estimate)), NMF::predict(estimate))
```

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'predict': object 'estimate' not found

```
result <- list(estimate, cluster)
```

> Error: object 'estimate' not found

**For clarity, my expr_rm has row indices as 1, 2, 3, 4,.. which indicates different genes and column headings as samples.**

Please suggest a solution for this soon!

Additional information (requested from comments):

```
>summary(expr_rm) - before conversion 
 Sample_C44_0001.genes.results Sample_C44_0002.genes.results Sample_C44_0003.genes.results Sample_C44_0005.genes.results 
 Length:145   Length:145 Length:145  Length:145  Class :character

 > summary(expr_rm) - after numeric type conversion
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   1.808   4.264   4.220   6.333  16.246
```

If in expr_rm is data.matrix() also, it gives the error like:

```
> median_centered_data<- expr_rm - med
Error in expr_rm - med : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from @maximilian-press, converted from comment:*

Sometimes casting to `as.numeric()` will convert from two-dimensional matrix to one-dimensional vector. Based on the output you put into comments (which would be helpful in the question), I wonder if this has occurred and caused an issue. For `data.matrix`, I suggest reading docs for that function- it should have returned only numeric, such that your `med` variable is likely not numeric, or there is a problem with your data. Possibly the tidyverse `tibble` created by `read_excel` might be the issue. I don't know enough tidyverse to say what exactly is going on.